# Android Facebook Like Button

Tags: android, fbsdklikebutton

Is it possible that I place a like button on my android app clicking which likes a post which is publicly available on facebook? I do not want any additional windows to open for the task except may be for first time authentication.

All questions asked so far are related to opening a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can perform a Like Action using Facebook's Open Graph API. In order to do so, you need to meet certain conditions:

1. The viewer of the in-app content is a Facebook user who has Facebook-authed and granted the app publish_actions permission
2. The in-app content has an Open Graph object page that is properly marked-up using Open Graph metatags
3. The viewer has intentionally clicked on a custom in-app “like button” associated with the in-app content

Steps at a high-level:

You need to first get the user's active `Session` (`com.facebook.Session`).

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
```

Then you need to ensure that the user has the `publish_actions` permission. If not, request them.

```
List<String> requestedPermissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
List<String> currentPermissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!currentPermissions.containsAll(requestedPermissions)) {
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, requestedPermissions);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
}
```

Finally, send your request to `"me/og.likes"`. Your request should include your `Session`, a `Bundle` including the Graph object you want to like, the HTTP method, and a callback that will execute once you receive a response.

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("object", myGraphObject);
Request request = new Request(session, "me/og.likes", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, myCallback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

You want to perform these steps in your button's `OnClickListener`.

Hope this helps!

Resources:

[Like Action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes)

[Publishing Conditions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes#publishing)